# dotenv module in node js return undefined

Tags: node.js, twilio

When i have written code for `whatsapp boat` using `twilio` module i get error in `.env` file

I have file structure like below:

```
/whatsappboatdemo
  | app.js
  | sendmsg.js
  | .env
  | package.json
```

And i have require `dotenv` like this in `app.js` file and `sendmsg.js`:

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

`.env` file content:

```
PORT=5000
TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID=******************************
```

So when i run `node app.js` it gives `undefined` for `process.env.PORT`.
I have tried with different file structure but i don't get idea so please help me in this , thanks in advance :)

Comment: You'll need to show more of your code. What do you have in your .env file? Where are you calling `require('dotenv').config()`? Where are you trying to read `process.env.PORT`?

Comment: i calling require in both app.js and sendmsh.js and i read process.env.PORT in app.js and process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID in sendmsg.js and both are written after require('dotenv').config() line

Answer (score 9):

It is really hard to debug your issue with what you provided. I would advise to check 3 things as these are common errors:

- Check if the format of the `.env` file is correct:
  i.e.: `PORT=9000` without any quotes etc.
- Log the require call:
  `console.log(require('dotenv').config())`
- Try to set the path manually and check if it works:
  `require('dotenv').config({path: __dirname + '/.env'})`

Comment: 1) yes i write it without quote
2) it print Object object
3) i tried but facing same issue

i update my question with info of .env and how app.js call .env

Comment: okay it seems like your file is loaded correctly - did you call `require('dotenv').config()`as soon as possible in `app.js`? - it should be called on the very top of the file otherwise the variables aren't accessable as well!

Comment: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/whatsappboatdemo/.env
getting this error but that .env file is there

Answer (score 0):

It might be nice to see how and when you require dotenv module.
Without further information I guess your error arise because when you are using your PORT variable, dotenv has not load it yet.

It is recommended to load dotenv module as soon as possible when loading your server.